# Returning from nested function in multiple functions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a set up where I need execute the same code in multiple functions.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    // Check if cookies are disabled, and redirect to login page if so
    if (cookiesDisabled(Request))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("cookie", "");
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    // Get the models
    AsdViewModel models = getAVM();
    if (models == null)
    {
        return Logout();
    }

    // Return view with the models passed in, etc.

}

public ActionResult OtherPage() {
    // Do cookie check so that just typing in MySite/Controller/OtherPage won't work
    // Get the models
    // Do some OtherPage() relevant calculations with the models
    // Return view with the models passed in, etc.
}
```

The problem here is that is that there is a lot of returning-out-of in this code. Wrapping the cookie check in a boolean return function seems redundant because I'd essentially just be saving one line (`ModelState.Add...`), and same with getting the models since I can't return out of everything from an inner function call. Is there a better way I should be organizing this, or how should I deal with the returns?

I know I can do something like `return OtherPage()` in Index to skip the repeated code, but I want the URL to reflect that the user is now in `OtherPage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an [IActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to check whether the user is logged in or whatever else you need with the cookies. An IActionFilter makes sense if you have common logic across many controllers (since you can annotate multiple controllers with the same filter).

If you only need your common logic in one controller, then you can override the OnActionExecuting method which is called before an action on your controller.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I'm looking for. How would I handle getting the models though? Would it be impossible for that to be part of the filter as I need the object to work with later on in the function?

Comment: The `getAVM` method should be available if you override the OnActionExecuting method of your controller. If you are implementing a filter, then you should be able to move the logic in the getAVM method in the filter and call it there.

Comment: I meant how I would access the model gotten from this filter, but I found the answer elsewhere (just need to set `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` apparently). Thanks for introducing me to the ActionFilter though, never looked into it before.